# How to implememt WinJS scrollview zoom not working

Tags: winjs

WinJS scrollview zoom not workingac

how to implement image zoom feature using scrollviewer in winjs application? i have tried samples from MSDN but that is not working..any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some CSS properties to implement image zoom. I have done this in the zoom demo of codeSHOW - http://codeshow.codeplex.com (source code) and http://aka.ms/codeshowapp (Windows 8 app).

It looks like this:

```
#container {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:scroll;
    -ms-content-zooming:zoom;
    -ms-content-zoom-limit-max:1000%;
    -ms-content-zoom-limit-min:20%;
}
```

Comment: do you know if there is a way to set a 'default zoom' value ?

Comment: @Jeremy: Nice :) And how would we reset the zoomed view with a double tap? Can this be done also via CSS or programmatically?

Comment: You can simply set the zoom of the `#container` element using JavaScript. Just select the element and then use the style property and then the zoom property. If you're using jQuery, you use `$('#container').css('zoom','100%')` and if you're not then you use something like `document.getElementById('container').style.zoom = '100%'`
You may also want to save the user's current zoom level. In that case you just want to save the value of the `zoom` property and then set it whenever you want to restore it.